# is "half stupid" idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I heard people said "**half stupid**" in Ghostbusters Film 2016. I am not sure if I misheard it. But:

> [half (adv)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/half_3): partly
>
> The chicken was only half cooked.

So, "**he is half stupid**" = "**he is partly stupid**"? is it right?

is "**half stupid**" idiomatic? or

is it common to say like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an idiomatic saying. You are correct in thinking that it means partly stupid. Usually it is used not as a judgement on intelligence, and more to comment that a person is half stupid, and half smart, or that they do stupid things or act in a stupid way some of the time, rather than they lack intelligence.